# Why does C/C++ require semicolons?

Tags: c++, c, syntax

I've been using Groovy, and it seems to be able to handle similar C/C++ syntax without semicolons. My question is, why does C/C++ require semicolons? Is it "that's just how they designed it", or are there ambiguities in the language that are preventable by using semicolons? If the latter, please give examples of such ambiguities.

Comment: A nice related question: [Why doesn't the compiler report a missing semicolon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40135392/why-doesnt-the-compiler-report-a-missing-semicolon)

Comment: Because it doesn't use newlines to separate statements.

Comment: @glauxosdever Other languages are able to differentiate between statement terminators, and those made for style. I'm under the impression that statement terminators wouldn't be required at all.

Comment: Such languages however require some special character sequences. For example the shell language requires \. Same with the C preprocessor.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "reason" as such. That is how the language constructs were written. The syntax includes the usage of `;` as the authors mentioned.

Just to quote a related paragraph from `C11`, chapter §5.1.1.2, *Translation phases*

> - White-space characters separating tokens are no longer significant. Each
>     preprocessing token is converted into a token. The resulting tokens are
>     syntactically and semantically analyzed and translated as a translation unit.

and, [newline is a whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).

Comment: Are there ambiguities in the syntax that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @ChrisSmith: because of the semicolons, you can safely ignore all whitespace - including end-of-lines. `int main(void) { return 0; }` is valid.

Comment: @ChrisSmith As c and c++ do not treat `\n` as a statement delimiter, there would be many ambiguities, yes.

Comment: @chris: if you just remove the semicolons, there would be lots of ambiguities. I can't know which ones you might be aware of.

Comment: @rici I'm only aware of the one posted in the main question comments. Other than that, I don't know of any.

Comment: @chris: Here's another one, then: `if(c)return a=42` also, consider a function declaration followed by a block statement. The largest category is the one referenced by that comment, though: two expressions which combined, form a single one.