# Why a syntax like "a=b--- // a newline, line ends without ;" does not produce syntax error?

Tags: c, syntax

What is the output of this program and how?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
     int a=0,b=10;
     a=b---
     printf("the value of b=%d",b);
     printf("the value of a=%d",a);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: is anybody going to explain this

Comment: Have you tried it? What output did you get? What output did you expect?

Comment: output is b=9 and a=-6.but i dont understand how it comes

Comment: Also, you might want to read [Why doesn't the compiler report a missing semicolon?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40135392/440558). As well as learning what [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) *returns*.

Comment: This is UB..... `a = b-- - printf("the value of b=%d",b);`

Comment: how variable 'a' got -6 value

Comment: Discussing this kind of nonsense programs is rather pointless.

Comment: Related stack overflow question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485088/what-does-the-operation-c-ab-mean

Comment: There is probably never a reason why you would want to do arithmetic with the result of printf though...

Comment: @MichaelWalz Agreed. The C tag seems to get these types of questions quite often.

Answer (score 5):

In your code, *writing*

```
 a=b---
 printf("the value of b=%d",b);
```

is same as

```
a = b---printf("the value of b=%d",b);
```

which is an expression with  **[undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)**, as an attempt is made to change and use the value of variable `b` in two *subexpressions* without a sequence point in between. Hence, the output of *this* code cannot be justified.

Without the above problem, in general, the syntax is similar to

```
x = (y--) -  (<return value of printf() call>)
```

which is a perfectly valid syntax.

---

Note:

Why `a = b---<something>` is treated as `a = (b--) - <something>` and **not** `a = b - -- <something>` is due to the [maximal munch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7485174/2173917) rule.

Comment: but in the above example b's value is 10 so how 'a' got -6

Comment: @ShahJunaid I get _the value of b=10the value of a=-7_

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, as others have said since this is undefined behaviour, the result could be anything . And while they're right, it doesn't explain why you get this specific answer in this specific compiler.

In practice b will usually be printed as 9, or 10 depending on whether the compiler does the decrememnt first or the printf first.

printf returns the number of characters printed. Which I think is 16 or 17 in this case.

So this is like writing `a = (b--) - 16;` b is 10 before the decrement and it's a post decrement so this is the value used.